# (Python) First letter of string printing twice

Tags: python

I am trying to put every letter that has an index of % 12 = 0 into a separate string. But for some reason it keeps printing the first letter of the string twice? FYI: the code is really basic, I'm not great at coding but trying to get better. Thanks.

```
string1 = 'nfhcizhfpntxolaqhpgvjehzsw'

final = ' '

for letter in string1:
    if (string1.index(letter) % 12 == 0):
        final = final + letter
        print (letter)
```

It outputs the following: nnos

When it should be: nos

Comment: Why don't you use slice? `final = string1[::12]`

Answer (score 8):

`index` returns the *first* occurrence of the letter in the string.

Since `n` is present at first position (it works) but also at another position, the second call *also* returns 0 and the letter is duplicated (it also has a nasty `O(n**2)` complexity because it searches from the beginning every time, even when it works)

The proper way is:

```
string1[::12]
```

slices the string to take each 12th character starting from index 0. Also avoids the ugly and underperformant string concatenation

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's working now. Just out of curiosity what exactly is [::12] doing?